# Use texture painting to determine transparent areas

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting

I want my "floor" plane to be transparent but with painted texture on it, but can't seem to fix the problem I have. I hope it makes sense, I have attached a photo for reference:

EDIT:
What I did so far (thanks @cegaton), I may be missing something
[image]

Comment: Did you save the painted texture before switching to rendered view? Sometimes it is necessary before the render view will give you the correct result.

Comment: Yep, I made sure to save everything before switching to rendered view but it still gave me the result above.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and post an image that shows your texture nodes and the image you are using to control the transparency It looks like you just need to invert the alpha channel, but without more information is hard to tell.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an examples using the painted texture to control the mix between diffuse and transparent shaders on a plane. Areas painted in white will be opaque, black will be transparent.

[image]

If you are getting the opposite effect switch the transparent and diffuse nodes. Or add a Color>Invert node between the texture and the Fac input fot the Mix Shader node so that the black areas are opaque and white becomes transparent.

Note that this texture painting controls the transparency only. The texture for the difuse shader has to be a different texture (or image), plugged to the color socket of the shader.

[image]

If you are going to paint directly on the 3D viewport make sure that you select the correct paint slot.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is working, but when I use a texture to paint it follows the color that's on the diffuse node. How can I make it not do that? Thanks

Comment: Plug the texture you need to the color socket of the diffuse node.

Comment: @Diviathan see edited answer

Comment: that's weird, I did exactly what you've shown but nothing is happening when I try to paint. It's just transparent

Comment: There is no way to guess what you did or did not do unless you add detailed information.

Comment: sorry, kinda new. I've edited my post with the detailed info on a GIF